# custom position column bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, col

i have a problem with column bootstrap when display on mobile device,

so this example :

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-5"> </div> 
   <div class="col-md-7"> </div>
</div>
```

when display on mobile, col-md-5 will appear at the top and col-md-7 will appear at the bottom.

but i want, col-md-5 appear bellow and col-md-7 appear at the top.

Any suggestion for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is correct practice but you could use the "hidden" or "visible" classes

'hidden':

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-5 hidden-xs hidden-sm">content abc </div> 
   <div class="col-md-7"> </div>
   <div class="col-md-5 hidden-md hidden-lg">content abc </div>
</div>
```

or 'visible':

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-5 visible-md visible-lg">content abc </div> 
   <div class="col-md-7"> </div>
   <div class="col-md-5 visible-xs visible-sm">content abc </div>
</div>
```

Here is a link for hidden and visible classes in bootstrap:
[Bootstrap responsive utilities](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_responsive_utilities.htm)

Comment: Thanks for reply, i hope this way can work for me. :)

Comment: No problem! glad to hear it helped.  Keep in mind I am not sure if this is or is not 'best practice'.  Just something that's worked for me and hasn't caused issues.

Answer (score 1):

There are two option Either put `col-md-7` up in html like:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-7"> </div>
   <div class="col-md-5"> </div> 
</div>
```

Or use position absolute for mobile device like:

```css
.row {
    position: relative;
}
.col-md-5 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
}
.col-md-7 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-5">col 5 </div> 
   <div class="col-md-7">col 7 </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply, previously I have tried to set bottom: 0px for md-5. but it does not work for me. set top: 20px for md-5 its work for me.